# Сортировка массива по возрастанию с числами и символами

Tags: javascript, массивы, алгоритм

Представим что есть массив:

```
arr['A100', 'A3', 'Z100', 'Z2']
```

Мне нужно написать сортировку по возрастанию, при которой массив приобретёт следующий вид:

```
arr['A3', 'A100', 'Z2', 'Z100']
```

Не могу придумать, как написать сортировку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
arr = ['A100', 'A3', 'Z100', 'Z2', 'B4', 'B1', 'C3'];
arr.sort((a, b) => {
  const _a = a.replace(/\d/, ''); // Берем только буквы
  const _b = b.replace(/\d/, '');
  
  if (_a < _b) return -1;
  if (_a > _b) return 1;
  // если буквы одинаковые сравниваем числа
  return a.replace(/\D/, '') - b.replace(/\D/, '');
});
console.log(arr);
```

[Подробнее](https://javascript.info/comparison) о сравнении строк и почему `'A100' < 'A2' => true`.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 7):

С [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) это делается фактически в одну строчку:

```js
const array = ["A100", "A3", "Z100", "Z2"]
const result = array.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: "base" }))

console.log(result)
// [ "A3", "A100", "Z2", "Z100" ]
```

При сравнении больших объемов лучше работать с ним через [Intl.Collator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator):

```js
const array = ["A100", "A3", "Z100", "Z2"]
const collator = new Intl.Collator(undefined, { numeric: true, sensitivity: "base" })
const result = array.sort(collator.compare)

console.log(result)
// [ "A3", "A100", "Z2", "Z100" ]
```

Comment: Очень интересное и полезное мне решение, спасибо огромное.